# Integration of GPRS printer

Tags: printers, gprs

I need to Integrate a GPRs printer to my WordPress with woocommerce website to print orders generated by the website. What is the File Path (or name of the file) that generates orders in active server page? And then Call Back url, Active Server Page that replies back?

The Printer has an INI file supplied by the manufacturer. It needs 2 pcs of information. FILE PATH and CALL BACK URL. I cannot figure out these addresses for my website.

There is no code involved only the file paths.

Will highly appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: You figured out the answer? Im kinda stuck here too

Answer (score 0):

GPRS printers expects order details to be supplied in specific format. Unless your printer came with custom WooCommerce plugin (seems unlikely) you will have to create ether custom WordPress/WooCommerce plugin or vanilla php scripts that would interact with printer and your backend, in this case WordPress/WooCommerce.